# Custom URL name for internal services

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns

I have a Kubernetes cluster. Some internal services (such as Kubernetes Dashboard) are only accessible via an OpenVPN instance I set up.

Per default kube-dns resolves services like: `http://{service-name}.{namespace-name}.svc.cluster.local`

For example http://kubernetes-dashboard.default.svc.cluster.local works beautifully.
How can I add custom DNS entries to make these services for example accessible via http://kubernetes-dashboard.mycompany ?

Comment: Could you explain do you want to access to your dashboard outside cluster or from inside the cluster?

Comment: I want to access it inside the cluster (when a user connects to it via the OpenVPN I set up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible with kubedns, but it is with coreDNS if you're on 1.11+.

[Custom DNS Entries For Kubernetes](https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/)

If that's not an option you could run your own lightweight DNS service with your custom rules inside the cluster and set it up as a "stub domain" in the kubedns configMap as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#kube-dns).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: kube-dns
    namespace: kube-system
data:
  stubDomains: |
    {"dashboard.mycompany": ["1.2.3.4"]}
```

In this case you'd want to change `1.2.3.4` to the ClusterIP of your new DNS server.

Comment: But how DNS will know where is dashboard.mycompany?

Comment: The stubDomain would make kubeDNS forward those dashboard.mycompany requests to a custom DNS service.